# How to handle user roles with Rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

In RethinkDB, there does not seem to be built-in support for user roles/access permissions.

This seems to be a common feature in most established databases, including MongoDB. We are worried that this gives processes that have access to the database too much access and us as developers little control over who can access what, leading to potential security issues.

I'm wondering: How big of an issue is this? Is there an alternative way to replicate this functionality without rethinDB supporting it out of the box?

Comment: Hey Zephyr, check out my new edit below!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

#### As of RethinkDB 2.3 which was just released, you can now add users and ACLs!

- [2.3 Release Blog Post](https://rethinkdb.com/blog/2.3-release/)
- [Users documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/permissions-and-accounts/)

**Original Answer**

access control (sometimes ACL) for RethinkDB is on [the road map](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4519) but in the mean time I recommend to either setup multiple instances divided by user permissions of RethinkDB along with an auth key:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/security/#securing-the-driver-port

> RethinkDB allows you to set an authentication key by modifying the
>   cluster_config system table. Once you set an authentication key,
>   client drivers will be required to pass the key to the server in order
>   to connect.

Hope that helps!